# What is the difference between abstract machines and automata?

Tags: automata

What is the difference between [abstract machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_machine) and [automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory)? Looking at the respective Wikipedia pages, only automata has a rigorous (mathematical) definition – abstract machines does not. And I can't find any source that clearly distinguishes the two; many sources leave it unclear as to whether there are any differences at all between the two.

P.S. If possible, I would appreciate a rigorous/mathematical definition of "abstract machines", contrasting this with the rigorous definition of automata.

P.P.S. There was no existing tag for "abstract-machines".

P.P.P.S. Are automata a subset of abstract machines?

Comment: "What is the difference between X and Y?" questions are typically hard to answer.  X and Y are two different things.  There are many differences.  You've already articulated one difference so you already have a start at answering your own question.  If you understand both X and Y, you should be able to figure out the differences yourself.  I think it's better to study X and Y, and then ask a specific question about some particular aspect of one that you don't understand.  Please ask only one question per post.  I see about three separate questions in this post.

Comment: The person writing the formal definition of "automaton" is mistaken. In my view this is the description of a (deterministic) [transition system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_system). A generic automaton model which includes that of a push-down automaton or a Turing machine should better distinguish internal states from external memory (pushdown or tape) rather than conflate the two types of states.